# dmesg says: "Warning: Outdated ThinkPad BIOS/EC firmware ... may be missing critical bug fixes". Why is it being so alarmist?

Tags: bios, thinkpad, firmware, x86, 32bit

## Background

I'm running Xubuntu 18.04.4 LTS on an ancient 32-bit ThinkPad T60.

dmesg reports:

```
[   27.726785] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad ACPI Extras v0.26  
[   27.726789] thinkpad_acpi: http://ibm-acpi.sf.net/  
[   27.726792] thinkpad_acpi: ThinkPad BIOS 79ETC9WW (2.09 ), EC 79HT50WW-1.07  
[   27.726794] thinkpad_acpi: Lenovo ThinkPad T60, model 2007VD6  
[   27.726796] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: Outdated ThinkPad BIOS/EC firmware  
[   27.726798] thinkpad_acpi: WARNING: This firmware may be missing critical bug fixes and/or important features
```

The warning in the last two lines appears somewhat alarmist.

What I've read online suggests (but does not prove) that thinkpad_acpi doesn't actually know of any specific critical bugs in my current firmware. It just knows that my firmware is outdated.

## My question

Regarding BIOS upgrades: I know that Lenovo might offer bootable firmware-upgrade ISOs for some ThinkPads on their website. Still, I lean towards the "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" camp.

Therefore, is it probably fine for me to ignore thinkpad_acpi's warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, the manufacturer hasn’t released firmware updates for your system since 2007, so it is probably fine for you to ignore the warning.

On more recent systems, firmware upgrades might be required to mitigate or fix many of the side-channel vulnerabilities discovered in recent years, which is perhaps the reason behind the somewhat alarmist message sent to the logs.